# Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of the same entity name twice on entities in different package but same name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

I have two Entities with the same name, but  in different package. For me it is obvious that should work. There is no duplicated name for entities.

But I am getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of the same entity name twice: Variant
```

I found solution, that tells me to use string value as Parameter for name attribute of `@Entity` annotation, f.e.:

```
@Entity(name="legal_Variant")
```

**But I don't like to use Strings in code. Can it be done other way? F.e. using java reflection, or configuring somehow `JPA` to use whole name (with package name)?**

For me it is quite strange. I thought that `JPA` takes care of package name also.

My classes code:

```
package insurance.models.liability.hiv;
@Entity
@Table(name="lLiability_Part_Hiv_Var")
public class Variant extends GenericDictionary<Variant> {
}

package insurance.models.liability.legal;
@Entity
@Table(name="liability_Part_Legal_Var")
public class Variant extends GenericDictionary<Variant> {}
```

Comment: Instead of using alias you can specify the class name along with package to avoid this error.                    @Entity(name="insurance.models.liability.hiv.Variant")
@Entity(name="insurance.models.liability.legal.Variant")

Comment: The JPA spec states clearly the default Entity name is the "unqualified" Entity class name. This name is used in JPQL queries, so using a fully-qualified class name might be a bit cumbersome. Using reflection or some such is not allowed with Java annotations, as the value must be resolved at compile-time. Strings in your Java code is not _always_ evil; e.g. you will typically use a String to specify any JPQL queries. You could go with semantic names (e.g. "HIV_Variant" and "Legal_Variant"). These would be readable and reasonably immune to class name changes.

Comment: Arin If I go with Your solution I will have to use whole name (with package) like `from insurance.models.liability.hiv.Variant ` while using HQL queries, So it will be a lot to write.

Comment: According to Brian Vosburgh answer I would use String names. But in further coding I will try to merge this entities into one, to avoid duplication. Maybe I will use `inheritance` to split specific elements to different `Entities`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175547/fix-for-hibernate-error-use-of-the-same-entity-name-twice?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in the mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <import class="insurance.models.liability.legal.Variant" rename="Var1" />
</hibernate-mapping>
```

You can now use an HQL query such as

```
from Var1
```

Reference: [Java Persistence with Hibernate (Chapter 4 pag.173/174)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885)

Comment: As long as I can use `Java Annotation` I won't go back for `XML`